# saving csv from excel loses decimal point precision

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

If I create a simple .csv file containing something like this:

```
01/22/2013,3.14159265358979323846264338
```

and proceed to open it up in excel, the cell will show a rounded number i.e. `3.141592654` and the formula bar will show the whole value. However if I make some changes and save the csv file, or just save the original file as a different csv file, the file will only contain the rounded number `3.141592654`, causing me to lose some decimal point precision.

I am writing these files out via a vba macro. I have tried :

```
ActiveWindow.DisplayFormulas=True
```

before the save command, and it works except it changes my date into a numeric format and I have not figured out a way to apply this format to only a range of cells. Is there some simple way to  keep my numeric precision?

Comment: Excel maxes out at about 15 digits for precision, so your number has too many decimals to be fully represented in Excel.  You could try importing the file as "text" and it should preserve the full number on export.

Comment: I am doing this via vba and there are many files. I would like to avoid importing the file at all costs.

Comment: You can only deal with numbers of that precision in excel by treating them as text.  The moment they're convert to numbers, you will lose precision.

Comment: @Ellipsis... what's the purpose of having such precision? Are you trying make someone pay till the `nth decimal point` ;) ?

Comment: ahah @bonCodigo, no they are rates

Comment: Are you doing any IR simulation, feeding these data?

Comment: @bonCodigo I'm actually just doing some reorganization of the csv structure, but I'd like the reorganized version to have the exact same values as the original

Comment: Then no choice but to store as `text` in your case.. as @Tim pointed out..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you know which cells are going to be affected, try something like

```
Range("MYNUMBERS").NumberFormat = "#0.000000000000000"
```

?

Comment: Will this give me trailing zero's in my csv format? I need the exact value

Comment: yes, it will give trailing zeros, but **0.1** is the same as **0.10000000000000**. Try using `Range("MYNUMBERS").NumberFormat = "#.###############"` if you are worried about the trailing zeros

Comment: @SeanCheshire that actually worked for me. Do you want to post it as an answer?

Comment: credit goes to @vinnyroe - I just added a different format string

Comment: @SeanCheshire usually has good points but it comes in comments :)